# make conditionally including other makefiles

Tags: bash, include, makefile, conditional-statements

I want to conditionally include makefiles depending on the contents of a xml file and product.
 
My xml file (myxml.xml):

```
<product1>
  <component1 dirname=dir1 />
  <component2 dirname=dir2 />
</product1>
<product2>
  <component1 dirname=dir1 />
  <component3 dirname=dir3 />
</product2>
```

In dir1 I have a config.mk file which looks like this:

```
SRC_JS+=dir1/file1.js
SRC_JS+=dir1/file2.js
SRC_HTML+=dir1/file3.html
```

Same for dir2 and dir3 which are all subdirs of the makefile dir.

Now I want depending on the specified product include certain config.mk files according to what is in the xml file.
So my makefile:

```
myjscode.js: myxml.xml
  read_dirs.py -p $PRODUCT $< > mydirs.txt
  while read mydir; do \
    include $$mydir/config.mk ; \
  done < mydirs.txt;
  js-compiler $(addprexis --js ,$SRC_JS) -output $@
```

Can this be done?
FYI: I'm using bash and the read_dirs.py script outputs a 'one-line-per-directory' list.

Answer (score 0):

First the easy part. The `include` directive cannot be in a command in a rule. Modify `read_dirs.py` to produce something like this (when `PRODUCT`="product2"):

```
include dir1/config.mk
include dir3/config.mk
```

Then in your makefile:

```
mydirs.mk: myxml.xml
    read_dirs.py -p $PRODUCT $< > $@

include mydirs.mk
```

There is no need for anything else to depend on `mydirs.mk`; since this makefile `includes` it, Make will rebuild it if necessary.

Now the hard part. I presume you want the choice of included makefiles to change not just when `myxml.xml` changes, but also when `PRODUCT` changes. But `PRODUCT` is not a file, so we have some choices. We could have a file `product.mk` that contains the `PRODUCT` variable. Or instead of `mydirs.mk` we could have a different file for each PRODUCT. Or we could force the building of `mydirs.mk` every time. It depends on how you set `PRODUCT` and what your priorities are.

Comment: But ...are you sure this is working (first part)? As far as I can see I first get the error that the include file isn't found (which is right because the include file has to be created). 
Then the target which has as prerequisite the SRC_JS variable is build. This fails because the SRC_JS variable has not been set. 
Then the include file is created. 
At this point I would expect the make file system to include the created include file and to recreate the target with the SRC_JS prerequisite. Unfortunately it's not happening that way. Something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
include $(shell read_dirs.py -p $(PRODUCT) myxml.xml|sed s,$$,/config.mk,)
myjscode.js: myxml.xml
    js-compiler ...
```